# Where to put business logic for a WPF Checkbox in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a class Record with properties below in the Model:

```
public class Record
{
     public string RecordID { get; set; }
     public string Status { get; set; }
     public string Profiler { get; set; }
     public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

In my View Model, I created a list from the class and I populated it from the database. This list is the itemsource of my datagridview and the columns are bound to the properties of the Record class:

```
  private List<Record> _recordList;

  public List<Record> RecordList
  {
        get { return _recordList; }
        set
        {
            _recordList= value;
            OnPropertyChanged("RecordList");
         }
  }

RecordList = new List<Record>();
```

Where do I put the logic for the IsChecked property bound to the Checkbox? Do I put in the setter of IsChecked property in the Model?

I have a row in datagrid (DV Record ID: All) that when its checkbox is checked, will also check/select other rows in the datagrid depending on a certain condition. Is it safe to put it in the setter?

[image]

Comment: What sort of logic do you want to implement?

Comment: @RobertHarvey In this case, when the row with the "All" Record ID's checkbox has been ticked, it will also tick other rows' checkboxes depending on a condition also updating the IsChecked property to true for the corresponding item.

Comment: Are You adding a dummy row in the RecordList to support that Top most ALL row?

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava Yeah that row is manually added to conform with the design specs.

Comment: I think you can have one Command in VM, to handle CheckBox Checked. Pass the Binding item to Command as Parameter. In the Command method you will have to (dirty) check for ALL item and react to it (i.e. loop through RecordList and set IsChecked True for all items).

Answer (score 1):

You can bind a Command to your checkbox like this:

```
<CheckBox Content="CheckBox"
      Command="{Binding CheckAllCommand}"
      CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

And then set `IsChecked` for all of your records in your View Model when the Command method executes.

```
public void CheckAllItems(bool isChecked)
{
    foreach(var item in RecordList)
    {
        item.IsChecked = isChecked;
    }
}
```